# Defining a Variable in a for loop using paste in r with an sqlQuery

Tags: r, for-loop, paste, qsqlquery

I am trying to define a variable in a for loop in r using the paste function, an example is as follows:

```
for (i in 1:length(XX)) {
    (paste0("Test",Name[i],sep="")) <- sqlQuery(channel, paste("SampleQuery", sep = ""))
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in (paste0("Test", Name[i], sep = "")) <- sqlQuery(channel,  : 
target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, the output of `paste0` is a character vector, not a variable. You can't use a character vector and the `<-` operator to assign into a variable, for that you need `assign()`.

But anyway, you'd be better off storing a list of related sql results in an actual `list`, rather than a bunch of variables. Keeps the environment tidier and easier to access programmatically afterward

Comment: Also, it looks like you are going to be retrieving a bunch of identical results, because nothing about `sqlQuery(channel, paste("SampleQuery", sep = ""))` changes between iterations of your loop as you've written it. But your question was mainly about assignment into a variable, so I limited the answer to that

Comment: Because of my desired output of individual .csv files and variables stored in the workspace I implemented assign() similar to the following code:

Comment: : for (i in 1:length(XX)) {
  for (j in 1:length(YY)){
    Varname <- paste("Test",XX[i],"_",YY[j],sep = "") 
    assign(Varname, sqlQuery(channel, "SampleQuery", sep = "")))
    write.csv(( sqlQuery(channel, "SampleQuery", sep = ""))),paste(Varname,".csv",sep=""),row.names=FALSE)
  }
}          I know this may not be the most efficient but is currently works for my situation. (my "SampleQuery" contains variable with [i] and [j])